# Vector Calculus - Evaluating $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = -\frac{1}{c} \partial_t \mathbf{B}$

Tags: vector-analysis, physics, cross-product, electromagnetism

For the life of me, I cannot remember how to solve equations similar to the cross product equations in Maxwell's equations. I haven't used vector calculus of this level in quite some time and could use some help with it. Given a specific electric field inbetween two perfect conductors (the inner conductor has an outer radius $a$ and the outer conductor has an inner radius $b$,
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t)
=
\dfrac{E_0}{2\pi} \dfrac{\hat{\mathbf{x}} x +\hat{\mathbf{y}}y}{x^2 + y^2} \cos\left(\omega\left(\frac{z}{c}-t\right)\right),
\end{equation}

how would you use the equation
$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = -\frac{1}{c} \partial_t \mathbf{B}$
to solve for the magnetic field? (If there is an easier alternative way to do this, I'm open to learning that method, as well.)

Note: The notation $\partial_t$ is simply shorthand for $\partial/\partial t$.

---

EDIT: The coaxial cable is along the $z$-axis.

Thanks!

Comment: Your vector, as written, is only 2D, so I'm not sure how you expect to take the curl. Should there be a $\hat{z}$ somewhere?

Comment: @Mattos, I added some more detail. Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: So the component in the $\hat{z}$ direction is $0$?

Comment: @Mattos Yes, it is

Comment: Ok, then your vector can be written as $$\vec{E} = \left( E_{1}, E_{2}, 0 \right)$$ with $$E_{i} = \frac{E_{0}}{2 \pi} \left( \frac{x_{i}}{x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2}} \right) \cos\left(\omega\left(\frac{x_{3}}{c}-t\right)\right)$$ Taking the curl \begin{align} \nabla \times \vec{E} &= \vec{i}(\partial_{x_{3}}E_{2}) - \vec{j}(\partial_{x_{3}}E_{1}) + \vec{k}(\partial_{x_{1}}E_{2} - \partial_{x_{2}}E_{1}) \\ &= \dots \end{align} Then integrate componentwise with respect to $t$ to get $\vec{B}$.

Comment: Duh, I should have thought of that from the beginning. Thank you. If you write up a similar solution, I'll accept your answer so you can get the points.